# Why implied `return` of arrow function doesn't work in this case (TS)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

**Update:**

At this point, I'm no longer able to repro it on local, after I ran

```
rm -rf node_mdoules/ && npm i
```

I'll keep the question, as it might be useful for others experiencing this bug. At the point of this writing, the bug is still reproducible in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4gype1nk/).

If someone finds a way to repro it reliably, do provide a repo as I know a few passionate coders curious enough to search for its root cause.

---

**Initial question**

I have this JavaScript code, which works:

```js
const iconsMap = new Map([
  ['Roofs', 'roofs'],
  ['Walls', 'walls'],
  ['Windows & Doors', 'doors'],
  ['Heating & Controls', 'heating'],
  ['Ventilation & Air Tightness', 'ventilation'],
  ['Renewables', 'renewables'],
  ['Others', 'others'],
  ['Default', 'home'],
]);

console.log(
  Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(iconsMap).map(([label, fileName]) => ({[label]: fileName})))
);
```

My first Typescript attempt was very close to original JS:

```ts
const iconsMap: Map<string, string> = new Map([
      ['Roofs', 'roofs'],
      ['Walls', 'walls'],
      ['Windows & Doors', 'doors'],
      ['Heating & Controls', 'heating'],
      ['Ventilation & Air Tightness', 'ventilation'],
      ['Renewables', 'renewables'],
      ['Others', 'others'],
      ['Default', 'home'],
    ]);
    
interface Dictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

console.log(
  Object.assign(
    {} as Dictionary<string>,
    ...Array.from(iconsMap).map(
      ([label, fileName]) => ({ [label]: fileName })
    )
  )
);
```

But it breaks with:

> VM325:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
> at new Function ()
> at exec (VM319 typescript.js:41)

For some reason, the implied `return` of arrow function `() => ({})` fails here. I need to do `() => { return {}; }`. So this works:

```
console.log(
  Object.assign(
    {} as Dictionary<string>,
    ...Array.from(iconsMap).map(([label, fileName]) => {
      return { [label]: fileName };
    })
  )
);
```

Could anyone explain why?

**Note:** I'm not interested in alternative ways to rewrite the above code (it's actually taken out of context to highlight the issue). I already re-rewrote the whole thing, I'm using a `.reduce()` and I'm happy enough with it.
For the curious types... cripter, actual implementation:

```ts
export const iconRegistry: Dictionary<string> = Array.from(iconsMap)
  .reduce((o, [label, fileName]) => ({
    ...o,
    [label]: require(`./assets/icons/measure/${fileName}.svg`)
  }), {} as Dictionary<string>);
```

But I'd like to understand why the implied `return` fails above.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: What does typescript.js (presumably the compiled result of that?) contain?

Comment: It looks like this: `console.log(Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(iconsMap).map(function ([label, fileName]) ({ [label]: fileName }))));`. Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4gype1nk/).

Comment: (Also, which version of Node are you using, and are you sure the TypeScript compile step succeeded? It would be very weird for TypeScript to compile successfully to syntactically invalid JavaScript.)

Comment: Well, `function ([label, fileName]) (` is definitely a syntax error. I can’t reproduce that behaviour in the TypeScript Playground, though; it compiles to an arrow function.

Comment: It fails both on my machine (node `v13.11.0`) and in jsfiddle (no idea what they have under the hood for Typescript implementation).

Comment: Can you make sure you’re using the latest version of the TypeScript compiler, and upgrade to a supported version of Node (14)?

Comment: On a side note you might be interested in using `Object.fromEntries()`

Comment: The project's typescript version is `"typescript": "3.9.6"`. Not the latest, but it's what? 2 months old?

Comment: Minimal example on JSFiddle is just `const foo = () => 5;`; compiles to the nonsense `var f = function () 5;`.

Comment: @tao: Can you try the simple `const foo = () => 5;`? If it doesn’t compile to an arrow function, you probably need to change your TypeScript configuration, but also it seems like a bug in the compiler to me. (Unless it’s targeting JavaScript 1.8, which would be really a weird thing for TypeScript to support and especially to default to.)

Comment: @Ry, thanks for the suggestion. As mentioned in the question, I already found a "fix". I simply wanted to understand the root of the problem. It's one of those cases where you check the syntax a lot of times thinking you have a typo but no, everything is what you intended.

Comment: @tao: Well, these are steps intended to diagnose the root of the problem, and to fix it properly (are you going to avoid expression-bodied arrow functions forever because of this weird bug?).

Comment: The best answer I have so far is: you have an older version of typescript. Which is somewhat false (I started this project 1 month ago, maybe less). I'm not going to update Typescript daily. Who does? Besides, I thought it's a more general problem (based on seeing the bug on both local machine and jsFiddle).

Comment: I doubt that the answer is upgrading to TypeScript 3.9.7, but it’s easy to check: upgrade to TypeScript 3.9.7 and see if it’s still broken. It’s not a general problem, what you wrote is supposed to work and tsc is supposed to generate syntactically valid JavaScript.

Comment: I found the version of TypeScript JSFiddle is using: 1.7.3, quite out of date (still not the kind of bug I’d expect for a stable version, but…). Are you invoking tsc (like you tried `tsc --version`) to compile, or going through some other tool?

Comment: @Ry- It's a Vue project installed about 1 month ago (with latest `@vue/cli`). I'll try the code in a new Vue project - I'm guessing now I'd get slightly newer deps (i.e: typescript `3.9.7`).

Comment: It fails in `3.9.7`, too.

Comment: If you run the single file through tsc directly, bypassing any Vue plugins, is the output still broken? Like `tsc path/to/the/file.ts`.

Comment: No, it doesn't fail in command line. And also, I'm not seeing any compile errors in the IDE (InteliJ, btw). So it must be a transform plugin. Something related to serve, i guess. But anyway, compiling an arrow function into `function() {}` is an insane error, when you think about it. One could rely on outer `this` being available inside the function.

Comment: Well, the `function` part could be okay. If you’re targeting ES5, for example, Babel knows how to put `this` into a variable in the containing scope. But dropping the braces is an insane error, yeah. How does your `babel.config.js` look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220007/discussion-between-tao-and-ry).

Answer (score 3):

The code you have compiles [without any errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlqSBZAhgBwFw1WgPNAJzjAHMAaGQ4kgPhgF4YwBTAd23QAoBtAWACgYQ4dwDkAJRAgAZhFEVRBKbNEBdMgOEjRAdRQAbfXIWsDRtRsFaYYncQAmIVhBgAyGABEpBYzFGOQHwtNazEACWYUKGo3GABhcCglcwUAC0jo0mCrLTEANWYwaP0ouHBYgEE4AhgAFTgSVKgWCF9RADdC4tLwbOsbCUK2FAAjfWY2giHTMYm+0NEAeSh0oIUQFeYg9RDc0Q9maRQAV30oeT9UkABbZnmhVQBKAG5dmAFiKC2j4GZPBGi4BQBAAnrhanQAN4hbgAa2YIKwVFIqiwtVe-AAvgIBIgICBxgA6fQgEicEKLEYAK2YwCghJQrQaYHJORgkMxMEZ-zpZTAwLByNoli0hLFFQIBBQIMJ0iU104CHAEBwj0J1y4byEPBKI2Y+go0jg4wAcihbk8GHROJCbLr9aiYEbTea-pjHm8PVYvS8gA)

[image]

## More

For any valid JavaScript Syntax, *you will never ever get a SyntaxError* if you just copy paste it to a TypeScript file. Because [TypeScript is syntactically a strict superset of JavaScript syntax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cj8z91XuOv8)

Comment: That is what I thought, and that is why I was so surprised to see it fails. However, this doesn't answer my question. Does it fail in the linked fiddle for you? If so, could you explain why?

Comment: @tao My initial explanation is that you're likely using an older version of TypeScript that doesn't incorporate support for ECMAScript 2017+ language features. You need to run `tsc` from the command-line (not from within your editor or IDE, as that be be using a private instance of `tsc` with a different version number to the edition of `tsc` in your `PATH`) and see if it works there or not - and if not, what does `tsc --version` say?

Comment: `Version 3.9.6`

Comment: This is in a Vue project. I haven't played with the configs (webpack, babel or ts) so it has the "latest" (~1 month ago) transform plugins and I'm expecting it to work. For the record, the compilerOptions says: `target: "esnext", module: "esnext", ..., lib: ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost" ]`.

Comment: @tao: Which transform plugins?

Comment: Sorry, I have more than one project open and I copy/pasted from the other one. Correct list of dependecies [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/0jt5pgnc/). So I'm guessing we're talking about `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`.

Answer (score 1):

Your TypeScript code is valid and it's correctly transpiled to JS, at least in TS 3.9.2. It seems to be a jsfiddle bug or a TS bug?. They use TS 1.7.3 in the jsfiddle you linked to, you can verify by executing `ts.version` in devtools console.

I added a log breakpoint in the script they use to transpile TS to JS which looks like this:

```
var transpiled = ts.transpile.apply(ts, [param[0], param[1], "filename", diagnostics]);
new Function(transpiled)();
```

Logging the `transpiled` variable shows that the code was transformed to this:

```
var iconsMap = new Map([
    ['Roofs', 'roofs'],
    ['Walls', 'walls'],
    ['Windows & Doors', 'doors'],
    ['Heating & Controls', 'heating'],
    ['Ventilation & Air Tightness', 'ventilation'],
    ['Renewables', 'renewables'],
    ['Others', 'others'],
    ['Default', 'home'],
]);
console.log(Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(iconsMap).map(function ([label, fileName]) ({ [label]: fileName }))));
```

Notice that the arrow function was transformed to:

```
function ([label, fileName]) ({ [label]: fileName })))
```

Which, of course, is invalid. I'd suggest you to use something like Quokka in vscode or `ts-node` if you want some local playground to try out things without having to setup stuff but you can, at least, have control over the TS version you're trying.

Comment: Welcome to [SO], Eddy and thank you for taking the time to answer. I'm afraid at the point of its addition your answer doesn't bring anything new to the table. Everything it states has already been outlined  in either the discussion below the question or the previous "answer" (which, just like yours, doesn't answer the actual question: *What is/was (technically) the root cause?*).  Also, I'm not using VSCode, but an IntelliJ based IDE (with powerful Typescript tooling).